# How to map this area conformally to the upper half-plane?

Tags: conformal-geometry

Could you help me, please? How to map this area conformally to the upper half-plane? I am so tired of solving this simple task, but I still cannot find the way to solve it.
$$\{z: \alpha< \text{arg}(z)< \pi-\alpha\}\setminus \{z=iy, y\geq 1\}, $$ with
$0< \alpha< \pi/2$

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First apply $z\mapsto z^{\pi/\alpha}$ to obtain the plane minus two opposing slits. 
[image]

---

You may already know that $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$ maps $\Bbb D-\{0\}\to \Bbb C-[-2,2]$, hence $z\mapsto \frac1{z+\frac1z}$ maps $\Bbb D\to \Bbb C-[\frac12,+\infty)-(-\infty,-\frac12]$, which is also a plane with two opposing slits.
[image]

---

Combine ...